# C++ Priority Queue with all data types

Tags: c++, priority-queue

We have to make a Priority Queue in C++. which should be able to handle all data types using a template. How should we go about doing this? P.s. We only started learning C++ 2 months ago after using java and C. Thanks

Comment: Use could always use [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any.html)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, he has to use `template`s... OP, check out this: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Comment: There is container adaptor `std::priority_queue` in the standard library (header `<queue>`); would this help you? Or is that a school assignment with the goal being to "implement it yourself?"

Comment: This question is worded ambiguously. Do you need to make a queue class that can handle any data type, but only one type per instance or do you need to make it so that a single class instance can accept any data type?

Comment: @l19 And for the record. cplusplus.com sucks. Try [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) instead.

Comment: In terms of _how to go about doing this_, I suggest you implement it first without templates and then think about which types to replace with template parameters and what the consequences will be. I find it hard to imagine a description of this procedure as a Stackoverflow answer. And I am sure you don't expect the SO community to write the actual code for you and put that as an answer, here, do you.

Comment: Have You tried generics in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key for writing a class that can handle all data types would be to use *templates*.
It's kind of similar to Java's generics.

Example:

```
template <typename T>
class MyPriorityQueue
{
     std::vector<T> data;
  public:
     void add(T const &d);
     void remove();
     void print();
};
```

So If You were to create an object of this class You would write:
`MyPriorityQueue<int> my_object;`
the typename *T* in the definition is automatically substituted with a type *int*

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part-1
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/